# Complete curved border not just corners

Tags: html, css

I have a template photo to create HTML for that.

[image]

The problem is marked in the image with arrows. There is a section under the slider which has a curved border (in light blue color), I tried to implement that with `border-radius` property and I did many tweaks around it. After all just the corners are curved or the radius is way more than what I need. How can I implement it in CSS? Thanks.

Comment: Don't think it's feasible to do in CSS. I would add a background-image to the white container with the top half of it being transparent (above the curve).

Answer (score 2):

You can make a big element that has more than 100% width and add Border-radius to it. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
.bigCircle {
  background: #ffffff;
  height:500px;
  width:200%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.bigCircle {
  background: #ffffff;
  height:500px;
  width:200%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 10px solid #00AAFF;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigCircle">
  <p> Wow you're huge!</p>
</div>
```

Edit: Removed Codepen link and added a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just have huge round object positioned to fit design:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 900px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.curve {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.curve:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 1000px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -750px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="curve"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The border-radius CSS property allows to define how rounded border corners are. The curve of each corner is defined using one or two radii, defining its shape: circle or ellipse.

Hope this will help to make your curved border for template photo.

```
/* The syntax of the first radius allows one to four values */
/* Radius is set for all 4 sides */
border-radius: 10px;

/* top-left-and-bottom-right | top-right-and-bottom-left */
border-radius: 10px 5%;

/* top-left | top-right-and-bottom-left | bottom-right */
border-radius: 2px 4px 2px;

/* top-left | top-right | bottom-right | bottom-left */
border-radius: 1px 0 3px 4px;

/* The syntax of the second radius allows one to four values */
/* (first radius values) / radius */
border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px;

/* (first radius values) / top-left-and-bottom-right | top-right-and-bottom-left */
border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px 30px;

/* (first radius values) / top-left | top-right-and-bottom-left | bottom-right */
border-radius: 10px 5px 2em / 20px 25px 30%;

/* (first radius values) / top-left | top-right | bottom-right | bottom-left */
border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px 25em 30px 35em;

border-radius: inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a div under your image container like,

```css
.oval-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px
}
.oval {
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120%;
  margin-left: -10%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval-container">
  <div class="oval">test</div>
</div>
```